# add rewrite_rules in WordPress custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

i try to `short url` of my custome page that in `my-pugin`

when i use my custom page i will url like bellow

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/testurl.php
```

but i want this

```
http://localhost/wordpress/testurl
```

i write this code in my plugin

```
function create_rewrite_rules($rules) {
        //print_r($rules);
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $newRule = array('/testurl' => 'wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/testurl.php');
        //echo $newRule;
        $newRules = $newRule + $rules;
        //$newRules = $newRule;
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($newRules);
        return $newRules;
    }

    function flush_rewrite_rules() {
        //echo 1;
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }

if(class_exists('MyPlugin'))
    $myPlugin = new MyPlugin();

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', array($myPlugin, 'create_rewrite_rules'));
add_filter('init', array($myPlugin, 'flush_rewrite_rules'));
```

but it cant help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you have to pay attention to :

- You have to flush the rewrite rules only on plugin activation/deactivation, not on init, in order to prevent performance issues.
- The `rewrite_rule` first parameter must be a regex.
- The `init` hook is an action, not a filter.

Below plugin code does work :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Rewrite test
*/

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^testurl?', 'wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/testurl.php', 'top');
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_flush_rewrites' );
function myplugin_flush_rewrites() {
    custom_rewrite_basic();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: hi i have few more question?